# Special character (like superscript) not render in react PDF

Tags: reactjs, react-pdfrenderer

On react pdf Renderer playground  ™ like superscript working.
But generating form my code its not working.

```
 <View style={styles.mainSecation}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>{chemicalData?.ChemicalName}</Text>
 </View>
```

Chemical name may contains superscript and special character. But its trims all special character

It should print all character

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.